# iPhone background app - why does whatsapp work and skype doesn't

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process, skype, whatsapp

I'm trying to wrap my head around how background apps work on iPhone. Specifically, Skype is not able to stay connected when the app is in the background, so you won't be able to receive calls/messages while in the background.

On the other hand, Whatsapp is connected all the time and you are able to receive messages even when in background.

Can someone explain the technicalities behind each app, the difference between them, and what prevents Skype from working like Whatsapp so its always connected?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can work out Whatsapp is using push notifications. I don't know why Skype hasn't implemented this as well, it seems odd not to, but it could be limitations with their architecture, or it could be just that it doesn't fit into their business model. Whatsapp is meant to be "always on", almost a replacement for SMS (which is what I use it for), whereas Skype is more of a "log in when you want to talk to someone" thing. I wouldn't want to be signed into Skype all the time. Neither app is using background processing. I don't think background processing has that much capability.

Comment: Skype will stay active in the background, you can set the time it will run in background via the settings app and it will keep running in the background to  receive VOIP calls. But it will check if you provider allows for VOIP calls over 3G/edge. If this is not the case Skype will only run in the background when on WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Whatsapp uses what's called Push Notifications. This allows an app that uses it to receive alerts/messages/notifications even when the app is not open on the iOS device.

As far as I remember, even Skype uses them to inform of incoming calls and new messages. You might have them disabled in Settings -> Skype -> Notifications.

For more info: 
http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonesoftwareterms/g/iphone-push-notifications.htm 
http://ipod.about.com/od/usingios4/qt/How-Iphone-Multitasking-Works.htm

Comment: @Taiha Sayed, If WhatsApp is using Push notifications then how does it handle the delivery receipts? I mean suppose if user A sends a message to user B (ios device and app is not opened), when User B get the push notification, we immediately see the delivery ticks in User A whatsapp. How do they handle that without background service?